# torch7: Unexpected 'counts' in k-Means Clustering

Tags: k-means, torch

I am trying to apply **k-means** clustering on a set of images (images are loaded as float `torch.Tensor`s) using the following segment of code:

```
print('[Clustering all samples...]')
local points = torch.Tensor(trsize, 3, 221, 221)
for i = 1,trsize do
  points[i] = trainData.data[i]:clone() -- dont want to modify the original tensors
end
points:resize(trsize, 3*221*221) -- to convert it to a 2-D tensor
local centroids, counts = unsup.kmeans(points, total_classes, 40, total_classes, nil, true)
print(counts)
```

When I observe the values in the `counts` tensor, I observe that it contains unexpected values, in the form of some entries being more than `trsize`, whereas the [documentation](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/blob/master/kmeans.lua) says that `counts` stores the counts per centroid. I expected that it means `counts[i]` equals the number of samples out of `trsize` belonging to cluster with centroid `centroids[i]`. Am I wrong in assuming so?

If that indeed is the case, shouldn't sample-to-centroid be a *hard-assignment* (i.e. shouldn't `counts[i]` sum to `trsize`, which clearly is not the case with my clustering)? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of the code, counts are [accumulated after each iteration](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/blob/1d4632e716dc3c82feecc7dd4b22549df442859f/kmeans.lua#L93-L94)

```
for i = 1,niter do
  -- k-means computations...

  -- total counts
  totalcounts:add(counts)
end
```

So in the end `counts:sum()` is a multiple of `niter`.

As a workaround you can use the callback to obtain the final counts (non-accumulated):

```
local maxiter = 40

local centroids, counts = unsup.kmeans(
  points,
  total_classes,
  maxiter,
  total_classes,
  function(i, _, totalcounts) if i < maxiter then totalcounts:zero() end end,
  true
)
```

As an alternative you can use [vlfeat.torch](https://github.com/deltheil/vlfeat.torch) and explicitly quantize your input points after kmeans to obtain these counts:

```
local assignments = kmeans:quantize(points)

local counts = torch.zeros(total_classes):int()

for i=1,total_classes do
  counts[i] = assignments:eq(i):sum()
end
```